# How can I delay execution of a function until two others have completed using $q?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the AngularJS implementation of $q.

Given the following functions:

```
   doTask1: function ($scope) {
       var defer = $q.defer();
       $http.get('/abc')
           .success(function (data) {
               defer.resolve();
           })
           .error(function () {
               defer.reject();
           });
       return defer.promise;
   },

   doTask2: function ($scope) {
       var defer = $q.defer();
       var x = 99;
       return defer.promise;
   },
```

I know I can delay execution of another function like this:

```
os.doTask1()
    .then(function () {
        doTask3();
});
```

I would like to start off doTask1 and doTask2 at the same time.
Is there a way I can do this and still delay execution so that
doTask3() will not execute until doTask1 and doTask2 have ended
with success.

Comment: knowing absolutely nothing about JS, I think the term you are looking for is something called a Callback. Googling javascript callback seemed to give many promising results, however, as I am not experienced in JS i cannot vouch for them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$q.all` is what you're looking for. ([Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q#methods_all))

`$q.all` takes multiple promises, either in an array or object, and returns a brand new promise that will be resolve when all the passed-in promises are resolved. If you passed in an array of promises, the new promise is resolved with an array of values which correspond to the promises:

```
$q.all([doTask1(), doTask2()]).then(function(results) {
  // results[0] == result of doTask1
  // results[1] == result of doTask2
  doTask3();
});
```

If you passed in an object of key-promise pairs, it will be resolved with an object with keys that match the object you passed in, each value nicely corresponding to the value of that key's resolved promise:

```
$q.all({one: doTask1(), two: doTask2()}).then(function(results) {
  // results.one == result of doTask1
  // results.two == result of doTask1
  doTask3();
});
```

Because of promise chaining (e.g., when you return a promise from a `then` function, it creates a new promise that resolves to the resolved value of the promise you returned), you can do some cool stuff:

```
var bothPromises = $q.all([doTask1(), doTask2()]);

var task3Promise = bothPromises.then(function(results) {
  var result1 = results[0];
  var result2 = results[1];
  return doTask3(result1, result2);
});

task3Promise.then(function(resultOfDoTask3) { ... });
```

It is worth nothing that if any of the promises passed to `$q.all` is rejected, the promise that is returned will also be rejected. See [the Angular `$q` documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) for more information.

---

This is (barely) tangential to the question, but I think it's a neat trick: if you happen to use CoffeeScript, you can use destructuring to get to the promises' resolved values.

For arrays:

```
$q.all([doTask1(), doTask2()]).then ([result1, result2]) ->
  # ...
```

And for objects

```
$q.all(one: doTask1(), two: doTask2()).then ({one, two}) ->
  # note that you have to use the same key names
  # as in the object you passed to `$q.all`
```